# Unable to access windows partition anymore

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have a dual-boot system with windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04. I was earlier able to access windows partition from ubuntu but that is not happening anymore. I don't even see the partition icon now. Please help.

Comment: Partition: /dev/sda3 Label: OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands,

```
cd /media
mkdir windows
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/windows
```

Now your windows partition will be mounted on `/media/windows`.